# Cant get the user openclinica apiKey

Tags: javascript, api, postman

This is the Endpoint for getting user account and its Api Key: 
https://dev.openclinica.com/apidoc/#api-User_Account-getAccountByUserName
using  the folling endpoint with postman

> POST http://89.221.253.174:8080/OpenClinica/pages/accounts/login?username=pranv&password=XXXX

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error and I dont know why.

I am not even quite sure if the URL is correct on my Postman.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The url should be:
POST http://89.221.253.174:8080/OpenClinica/j_spring_security_check?username=pranv&password=XXXX

pages/accounts/login submits to j_spring_security_check